# How to randomly get a double from a range

Tags: java, random

I'm actually working an a project and I have a problem :
I have to generate a random `Double` value from range `[a, b]`. By searching on internet, some people say that the following formula works :

```
b + (b - a) * random.nextDouble();
```

But if we do some calculus, we found that it's impossible for `a` to be included.

How can I do such a thing ? Does anyone have any clue ?

Thanks in advance for the help !

Comment: are you absolutely sure you need the whole range `[a, b]`?  In my experience it's _very_ unusual for both ends of a random range to be inclusive.

Comment: Yes I'm sure. And if it can help, my instructor told me to use `random.nextDouble();` and `random.nextInt();`

Comment: @Robert it is _not_ a duplicate of that because that question and answers assume the usual convention that the top of the range is _exclusive_.

Comment: @Robert already so this tread, but that's the same problem, `a` or `b` will not be included

Comment: @Alnitak yes, I see. Thanks for the hint! Is there a option to remove my flag? I tried it with deleting my comment but that did not work...

Comment: @Robert I don't see any flag.

Comment: @Dayrona it would be interesting to see whether your instructor is aware of just how unlikely it is that the inclusive version will produce a result different to the exclusive version...

Comment: @Alnitak My instructor was aware of that problem and said, few days after I asked here, that I can use my method or @Tarek's one because the probability of reaching `k` or `l` is infinitesimal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `nextDouble` function works by creating a 53 bit integer, and then dividing it by 2 ^ 53.  From the javadocs:

```
 public double nextDouble() {
      return (((long)next(26) << 27) + next(27))
          / (double)(1L << 53);
 }
```

This therefore produces the range `[0, 1)` - the upper bound approaching the limit of `(n - 1) / n`.

To create the fully inclusive range instead, create that 53 bit integer yourself, but divide instead by `(2 ^ 53) - 1`.

Note that to all intents and purposes the difference between inclusive and exclusive barely matters - the odds of hitting `1.0` exactly with the modified code is `1 / ((2 ^ 53) - 1)` - an almost infinitesimally small number.

Furthermore, this division by `(2 ^ 53) - 1` will be potentially a lot slower than the original code.  Division by `2 ^ n` is utterly trivial for a CPU because all it does is decrement the floating point exponent and potentially left shift the mantissa.  That `- 1` on the divisor makes the division a lot more long-winded, and may even make the resulting sequence less random than it should in the lower order bits.

Answer (score 2):

This is more logical

```
 a + (b - a) * random.nextDouble();
```

**Update:**

But this logic will exclude b, since random.nextDouble(); ranges between [0,1), which means it doesn't include 1.

Comment: ["chosen (approximately) uniformly from the range 0.0d (inclusive) to 1.0d (**exclusive**)"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextDouble%28%29)

Comment: From the javadoc, `random.nextDouble()` generate a random number between 0 (included) and 1 (excluded)

Comment: Got the reason now. @TheLostMind

Comment: @Tarek your answer is technically incorrect - it does not solve the OP's issue.  IMHO you should delete it.

Comment: I do think that it provides a partial solution, because his previous logic b+(b-a) was not correct. I already corrected my mistake. I think this answer is helpful to others, because your answer did not address this issue.

Comment: His logic was correct for the range that he described - `(a, b]`.  Changing the code to produce `[a, b)` instead does not fix his problem, and is addressed in numerous other questions here.  The upvotes you received were only from other people that also failed to understand the problem.

Comment: @Alnitak: Sorry sir! How, b+(b-a) can be a correct logic for (a,b] range, may I know please? if b=3.0, a=2.0 , can 3.0+(3.0-2.0)*random.nextDouble() produce a double between (2.0,3.0] unless random.nextDouble() is exactly 0.0. What will happen, if say, random.nextDouble() generates 0.5? May I get a upvote please?

Comment: you're right - I misread it as b + (a - b).  You still don't get an upvote, though, _because you didn't actually answer the question_.

Comment: If you please read the question again, he asked: "it's impossible for a to be included. How can I do such a thing ?" The question demanded to add the lower bound a and my code do that. You provided a partial solution about how to acheive [0,1] with random.nextDouble() alternative function, but with his algorithm, it would generate a wrong answer which you did not address but was addressed by my code. So, if I delete my answer, he will be left with wrong algorithm. I agree that it will be best, if my solution can provide the full range [a,b] and I will work on that. Thanks for the up vote.